# Oracle database login

Tags: database, oracle, security, unix

A database administrator has used to connect to oracle database on unix operating system by using the following:

```
$ sqlplus  sys/sysPass1@orcl as sysdba
```

What are the big mistakes in the previous method to connect?

What do you suggest to avoid such mistakes?

Please help me ...

Comment: What kind of mistakes are you encountering?

Comment: Were you actually sitting down, taking the test, when you posted this question?

Answer (score 1):

That it exposes the password to other users running a ps -e command.

I'd suggest using an Oracle wallet to avoid the need to specify a password/

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to connect to the database in this way - unless you are using Oracle RAC.
If the environment variables ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are correctly used and the unix user is in the DBA group and you are on the DB server a

`sqlplus / as sysdba`

is still working.

If you are using a script it is always a good idea to connect with

`sqlplus /nolog @ script.sql`

and in the script as first line

`connect user/password@tnsnames`

or, if the script is running on the database server

`connect user/password`